# postgresql select * from users with Haskell

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I'm doing a simple exercise trying to select users from a table:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- connect localPG
    mapM_ print =<< (query conn "select * from users where name = ?" (Only ("jane"::String)) :: IO [String])
```

I get the error:

```
Incompatible {errSQLType = "int4", errSQLTableOid = Just (Oid 24592), errSQLField = "id", errHaskellType = "Char", errMessage = ""}
```

I'm using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.4/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html

It looks like the returned value from the PostgreSQL cannot be converted to a Haskell object as mentioned in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.7.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html

Note that I casted by query to `IO [String]`. What should I cast it to?

Comment: You seem to be selecting everything from the table, while your type annotation specifies only a single `String` column.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Actually, it's worse than that: the given type annotation specifies multiple `Char` columns.

Answer (score 2):

We can't know what you should cast it to without knowing the database schema. For quick and dirty experimentation, though, the general idea is to use a tuple with the same types as the columns of the given table, and in the same order.

Production code will typically define a new custom data type with the right fields, and implement `FromRow` for that type.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that I casted by query to IO [String]. What should I cast it to?

No, you didn't and this is the problem.  That isn't a "cast" but a declaration of the type.  In more words, you are declaring "this call will return a list of rows, each row will be columns of one character each".

While Haskell can make the declaration true within the confines of the Haskell type system (by calling the conversion for psql characters), this isn't the true type of the sql schema and isn't what you want.  Instead try to be less dense with your code and provide the actual type of each column.  Using dmwit's suggested quick-and-dirty method you could do something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- connect localPG
    res <- query conn "select * from users where name = ?" (Only ("jane"::String)) :: IO [String]
    mapM_ printRow res

printRow :: -- This is the schema, you tell us
            -- for example only, perhaps something like:
    (String, String, Int, String) -> IO ()
printRow = print
```